# NetBeans output Console : " line is too long ,please switch to wrapped mode to see whole line". Solve the Error

Tags: netbeans

How to solve that error?

I am Using NetBeans IDE 8.2-
I am keep getting this message: ...this line is too long, please switch to wrapped mode to see the whole line...

Comment: The message already tells you what to do, so what exactly is your question?

Comment: my code is sum of three number . But I keep getting that message

Comment: So what's the problem? Right click in the output window and select "Wrap"